# How can I make a template Icon in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, template-design

I created the attached icon for my client. Now my client wants to have the original AI file and he asked me to make a template so that he can change the flag in shades anytime he wants.

I was wondering if there's an easy way to do it? so that even a person having a little knowledge of AI can do that.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: So this might not fit the use case, but the first thought I had, was an `.svg` file: [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/0k1rhp8u/). There are some online svg editors, but at the same time I kinda felt like.. Might as well use illustrator to do it.

Answer (score 2):

By using `Clipping Masks` and locking your layers, that's how I would do it.

Here is a sunglasses(ish) shape that I just made.

[image: glasses]

Copy the two circular paths that make up the lenses and past them in place.  I have hidden the frames, so you can better see the lens circles.

[image: lenses]

Place the design that you wish to have fill your lenses below everything else (doesn't really need to be below *everything* else, just the lenses).

[image: design]

Now, with the lens circles and the lens design both selected (make sure that the circles are **on top** of whatever you want on your lenses).

[image: hierarchy]

Create a clipping mask

[image: menu]

Giving you this

[image: end result]

Then, just lock the layers that you don't want mistakenly altered.

[image: locked]